# How to remove same entry from list after print in python

Tags: python, list

```
failist = [123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,901]

while len(failist) > 0:

    for x in range(len(failist)):
        print("Removing" + str(failist[x]))
        failist.remove(failist[x])
```

Comment: the while loop isn't necessary

Comment: Just use `failist.clear()` *after* the loop; there doesn't appear to be any reason to remote the items one at a time *inside* the loop.

Comment: alternatively, you can simply check if the list is non-empty and pop the entries, or not use the list again and let it be destroyed when you leave a function containing it

Comment: Why do you need to loop this way anyway? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically, I'm working on a project; it will send a message to a mobile number and will remove it from the list otherwise it will repeat the process.

Comment: @KaleemKhan don't remove/add to a list while you iterate over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the best way to right the code you have in a concise manner.

```py
failist = [123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,901]
# while loop not necessary
for x in failist:
    print("Removing: ", x) # removed the concatenation and type cast
failist.clear() # clear list instead of removing one by one
```

Comment: Great... thank you so much it's done by replacing failist[x] to x.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to iterate by index.

```
failist = [123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,901]

while failist:
    print('removing: ', failist[0])
    failist.remove(failist[0])
```

Output:

```
removing:  123
removing:  234
removing:  345
removing:  456
removing:  567
removing:  678
removing:  789
removing:  890
removing:  901
```

Comment: I want to remove numbers by matching phase, not from 0 index

Comment: You should add your desired output then.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate using a copy of *failist* like in the example bellow:

```
failist = [123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,901]

for number in failist[:]:
    print("Removing " + int(number))
    failist.remove(number)
```

the **[:]** operator creates a copy of your list so you can iterate and remove data from *failist* without missing any value.